# How do i create XY Chart in Java with two variables?

Tags: java, charts

I have a problem with generated a XY Chart in Java . I have three objects and for them I determinate a price and a weight . Now I have two generate two charts : one that have x axis the object , and on y the price and the other one on y axis have the weight .  I created the buttons and I declared graphmodifier= 1 for the first chart and graphmodifier=2 for the second one.

Code:

```
private XYDataset createDataSet() { String[] data = inputStringData();
   storeData(data);

    XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("");
    if (graphmodifier == 1) {

        series1 = new XYSeries("Price");
        for (int i = 0; i < speed.length; i++) {

        }
    } else {

        series1 = new XYSeries("weigh");

    }
    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    dataset.addSeries(series1);
    return dataset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, the only downside is that it is commercial >> http://www.softwarefx.com/products/chartfx/?selPlat=VS

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. Its rich in features and is free as well. http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html